# twitter bootstrap 3 images within carousel auto resize to fit and navbar remove

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am pretty satisfied with my carousel which is working fine execp two things which i would like to change and counting your help.

1: How to make images to be fitted to carusel? Right now they are cutted from bottom - see on image (blue line)
2. Important: I would like to stay height of carusel images as it is right now - by the way which option in my code specyfing it?
3. How to remove - i think navbar on the top of my carusel? What it could be use for by the way? (navbar marked on red)
4. What is the purpose of id called: myCaousel within div?

[image]

code:

carousel:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="new/3.jpg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img alt="" src="new/1.jpg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img alt="" src="new/2.jpg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

css:

```
   /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: -90px;             /* odstep miedzy carusel slider a nastepnym containerem tzn O mnie */
    }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 550px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px; 
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
```

**EDIT - for further discussion:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
   /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: -90px;             /* odstep miedzy carusel slider a nastepnym containerem tzn O mnie */
    }

.slider-size {
    height: 500px;
}

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 550px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px; 
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <div style="background:url('http://jonesaccounting.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider-background-blue.fw_-1.png') top center no-repeat; " class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url('http://jonesaccounting.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider-background-blue.fw_-1.png') top center no-repeat; " class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url('http://jonesaccounting.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider-background-blue.fw_-1.png') top center no-repeat; " class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.END CAROUSEL DIV -->
    </div><!-- /.END MYCAROUSEL DIV -->
</div><!-- /.END BSEXAMPLE -->
</div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/1.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/2.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/3.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.END CAROUSEL DIV -->
    </div><!-- /.END MYCAROUSEL DIV -->
</div><!-- /.END BSEXAMPLE -->
</div>
</div>
```

To make image fit in carousel you will need to give image in background and give then give background image to css property (background-size:cover) 
this will make the images to be fit in carousel

**for use of ID**  (in this case id="myCarousel") for carousel controls to function properly.

Comment: hi can you tell me where inside my css i have to change that?

Comment: you need to add only height to  .slider-size class

Comment: dont see slider size within my custom css.

Comment: hi i implemented according to your input but after the change my pictures are diffrent distance betwen botton and next container from up to down, and also distance from left and right has been reduced. How to c=fix that left riht is maximized and from bottom to word "Kilka slow" as was before. The target change is to keep as i had it oryginally but centralize image thats it.

Comment: you need to give images size same and width to 100% so it will come full screen width